# PHP Reflection: identify correct constructor

Tags: php, reflection

PHP ReflectionClass::getConstructor() gives a class's constructor.

If a child class has no constructor defined but its parent class does, then the parent constructor is returned.

Is there a way to distinguish whether the constructor came from a child class or its parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getParentClass`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php) method of the `ReflectionClass` class to determine the constructor function of each parent class by using recursion.

```
<?php

class point {
   function __construct($x) {$this->x=$x;}
}

class point2 extends point{
   function __construct($x,$y) {$this->x=$x;$this->y=$y;}
}

class point3 extends point2 {
  function __construct($x,$y,$z) {$this->x=$x;$this->y=$y;$this->z=$z;}
}

$ref= new ReflectionClass('point3');
do {
$constructor = $ref->getConstructor();
var_dump($constructor);}
while ($ref = $ref->getParentClass());
?>
```

[Teh playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/bQx2NanlRAVKvZTA)

This outputs:

```
object(ReflectionMethod)#3 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "__construct"
  ["class"]=>
  string(6) "point3"
}
object(ReflectionMethod)#2 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "__construct"
  ["class"]=>
  string(6) "point2"
}
object(ReflectionMethod)#4 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "__construct"
  ["class"]=>
  string(5) "point"
}
```

and by hashing out the various `__construct` functions, you can determine which ones are called.

Comment: Your loop is pretty much exactly what I have. However, if point3 has no constructor function you get the same constructor (point2) twice, which is the heart of my problem. I don't understand your comment re hashing the constructors. Will that resolve this duplication?

Comment: If you comment out the constructor functions in the various ways possible (i.e. 'hash' them out), you get 8 different results, which allows you to determine which constructors are being called. For example, if point2 is called twice, this indicates that the constructor for point3 is the same as for point2. i.e. it doesn't have one.

Comment: Thanks! Leave that with me. I thought 'hash' meant something different. Will revert later.

Comment: Actually its much simpler than all that: ReflectionMethod has the method's class right there as a public property.